# How to Parse an .etl file using Powershell and get the payload, without converting to another filetype

Tags: powershell

I have tried:

```
$path = "xxx/xxx.etl"
Get-WinEvent -path $path -Oldest
```

but it's only showing the events and not the payload.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent library is what you need: https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/blob/master/documentation/TraceEvent/TraceEventLibrary.md

Here's an example of how to use it in PowerShell, tested in 5.1 and 7.1.

```
using namespace Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Etlx
using namespace System.Security.Principal

# Check if Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent is installed, else install before continuing
if (-not (Get-Package -Name Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    "TraceEvent package not foumd, trying to install. This may take a few minutes..."
    # Veryify the current user is part of the administrators group before trying to install package
    if ([WindowsPrincipal]::new([WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsinRole([WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
        [void](Install-Package -Name Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent -Force -ForceBootstrap)
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Administrator privileges required to install TraceEvent package, re-run script as administrator."
        exit
    }
}
$PackagePath = Get-Package -Name Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Source
$AssemblyPath =  Join-Path (Split-Path $PackagePath) '\lib\net45\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent.dll'
try {
    "Loading assembly."
    Add-Type -Path $AssemblyPath
}
catch {
    'Add-Type failed, using [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom'
    [void]([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($AssemblyPath))
}
$EtlFile = 'C:\script\lab\Tests\ETL\NtKernel.etl'
$TraceLog = [TraceLog]::OpenOrConvert($EtlFile)
```

You'll need to change the path of $EtlFile of course.

After running you should have all your events in `$TraceLog.Events`, including payload. If you run eg. `@($TraceLog.Events)[0] | Get-Member *payload*` you'll get this list of payload-related Methods:

```
Name                MemberType Definition
----                ---------- ----------
PayloadByName       Method     System.Object PayloadByName(string propertyName)
PayloadIndex        Method     int PayloadIndex(string propertyName)
PayloadString       Method     string PayloadString(int index, System.IFormatProvider formatProvider)
PayloadStringByName Method     string PayloadStringByName(string propertyName, System.IFormatProvider formatProvider)
PayloadValue        Method     System.Object PayloadValue(int index)
PayloadNames        Property   string[] PayloadNames {get;}
```

You can install the library prior to running the script with

```
Install-Package -Name Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent
```

or just run the script as administrator the first time. Note that installing the package can take a while so just let it run.

If you run into problems with the package installation it may be worth making sure your PackageManagement module is up to date with something like:

```
Update-Module -Name PackageManagement -Verbose
```